Converting Eth price correctly in JS
i have this snippet i fixed the hex and suggested in the comments. Console error is here https://ibb.co/LShTFxX Metamask is still throwing large number

console.log('the conversion factor is', conversionFactor);

if(conversionFactor != null){
    const networkStatus = await checkNetwork('ethereum'); 
    if(networkStatus){
        console.log('its okay to send transaction we are on the correct network');
        transactionInProgress = true;
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        const userWallet = accounts[0];
        const recipientWallet = RoysWallet; 
        const weiParameter = amountToSendFloat;//*conversionFactor;
        const desiredDecimalPlaces = 7; 
        let weiParameterStr = weiParameter.toString();
        let decimalIndex = weiParameterStr.indexOf('.');

        if (decimalIndex !== -1) {
          let decimalPlaces = weiParameterStr.length - decimalIndex - 1;
          if (decimalPlaces > desiredDecimalPlaces) {
            weiParameterStr = weiParameterStr.slice(0, decimalIndex + desiredDecimalPlaces + 1);
          }
        }

        const finalWeiParameter = parseFloat(weiParameterStr);
        //console.log(finalWeiParameter.toString());
        const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(finalWeiParameter.toString(), 'ether');
        //const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountToSendString, 'ether');
        // Convert Wei to Hex
        const amountInHex = web3.utils.toHex(amountInWei);
        // might not be hexing correctly test individually
        console.log(`Amount in Hex: ${amountInHex}`); 
        const transactionObject = {
            from: userWallet, 
            to: recipientWallet,
            value: amountInHex
        };
        console.log('trying to send string:', amountToSendString);
        console.log('final Wei paramater', finalWeiParameter);
        console.log('amount to send float', amountToSendFloat);
        console.log('in WEI', amountInWei);
        console.log('in hex', amountInHex);

        const response = await window.ethereum.request({
            method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
            params: [transactionObject]
        });
    }
}else{
    
}```


const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountToSendFloat, 'ether')
^ You don't need conversionFactor. Simply replace with this snippet. Provide amountToSendFloat as a string .
The problem with providing amountToSendFloat as float is that decimal places are harder to represent in binary (that's how they are stored to save space) so it will automatically be approximated if decimals go deep.
There is one important thing to keep in mind if your amountToSendFloat has more than 18 decimals you need to do something with the decimals after the 18th decimal. Either truncate, round up to 18th place or round down to 18th place.
eg. 5.1234567891234567891 has 19 decimals you need to do something with the final value 1.
EDIT
        function manipulateDecimals(strNum){ 

            // Decimal Manipulation logic here ...
            // returned value should be string
            return strNum 

        }

        // Removed `if(conversionFactor != null)`
        const networkStatus = await checkNetwork('ethereum'); 
        
        // Let the input amount be in string and not float to avoid rounnding errors
        let amountToSendStr = "1.23432432132"

        // Manipulate `amountToSendStr` to your desired decimal place  keep result in string . 
        amountToSendStr=manipulateDecimals(amountToSendStr)

         

        if(networkStatus){
            console.log('its okay to send transaction we are on the correct network');
            transactionInProgress = true;
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const userWallet = accounts[0];
            const recipientWallet = RoysWallet; 
            
            // Removed multiplication by conversion factor const weiParameter = amountToSendFloat*conversionFactor;
            // Replaced with correct code snippet 
            const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountToSendStr, 'ether')// Convert amount to wei
            
            // Print and check amount in wei . Simply pass this to your `transactionObject` as  `value`
            console.log("amountInWei: ", amountInWei)

        }

EDIT2
Use
const transactionObject = {
    from: userWallet, // deprecated in firefox window.ethereum.selectedAddress,
    to: recipientWallet,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(amountInWei)
};

Metamask expects value field in HEX . web3.utils.toHex(amountInWei) does the job
https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/eth_sendtransaction/
Complete snippet -
        function manipulateDecimals(strNum){ 

            // Decimal Manipulation logic here ...
            // returned value should be string
            return strNum 

        }

        // Removed `if(conversionFactor != null)`
        const networkStatus = await checkNetwork('ethereum'); 

        // Let the input amount be in string and not float to avoid rounnding errors
        let amountToSendStr = "1.23432432132"

        // Manipulate `amountToSendStr` to your desired decimal place  keep result in string . 
        amountToSendStr=manipulateDecimals(amountToSendStr)



        if(networkStatus){
            console.log('its okay to send transaction we are on the correct network');
            transactionInProgress = true;
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            const userWallet = accounts[0];
            const recipientWallet = RoysWallet; 

            // Removed multiplication by conversion factor const weiParameter = amountToSendFloat*conversionFactor;
            // Replaced with correct code snippet 
            const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountToSendStr, 'ether')// Convert amount to wei

            // Print and check amount in wei . Simply pass this to your `transactionObject` as  `value`
            console.log("amountInWei: ", amountInWei)

        }
    const transactionObject = {
    from: userWallet, // deprecated in firefox window.ethereum.selectedAddress,
    to: recipientWallet,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(amountInWei) // Converting to HEX !!!
};
// Proceed to broadcast transaction object


EDIT 3
Here's my complete code . It triggers metamask and sends 0.23432432132 eth on confirmation . Exactly equal to the amount that I have mentioned in the code . https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x1a81e02e65a35cc0ceec1ad94c6c908ac0bf959b7bb24a9247dee6f2b8b1ec81

List item

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MetaMask Transaction Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.5.2/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
async function connectToMetaMask(){
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);  // Replace with your Ethereum node URL

function manipulateDecimals(strNum){ 

    // Decimal Manipulation logic here ...
    // returned value should be string
    return strNum 

}


// Let the input amount be in string and not float to avoid rounnding errors
let amountToSendStr = "0.23432432132"

// Manipulate `amountToSendStr` to your desired decimal place  keep result in string . 
amountToSendStr=manipulateDecimals(amountToSendStr)

console.log('its okay to send transaction we are on the correct network');
transactionInProgress = true;
let accounts 
if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {

accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })

}


const userWallet = accounts[0];
const recipientWallet = userWallet;

// Removed multiplication by conversion factor const weiParameter = amountToSendFloat*conversionFactor;
// Replaced with correct code snippet 
const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountToSendStr, 'ether')// Convert amount to wei

// Print and check amount in wei . Simply pass this to your `transactionObject` as  `value`
console.log("amountInWei: ", amountInWei)

const transactionObject = {
    from: userWallet, // deprecated in firefox window.ethereum.selectedAddress,
    to: recipientWallet,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(amountInWei)
};
console.log('trying to send', amountToSendStr);
console.log('in WEI', amountInWei);

// Send the transaction using MetaMask
const response = await window.ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params: [transactionObject]
});
}
alert("DONE ")


// Automatically attempt to connect to MetaMask when the page is loaded
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    connectToMetaMask();
})


    </script>
</body>
</html>


okay i will change to string and see what happens.

it did not work. If i send 1.4 for example it gives me a lot more like i need to convert it

@RoyBUrson Paste the code snippet on pastebin and share the link

the code is publicly available at https://github.com/bursonskullz/Web3-Art-Website/blob/main/myfunctions.js the metamask transaction is on line 5155 or you can search using Ctl+F and search for conversion factor. The code is also running online at https://bursonskullz.com in my private server using this conversion factor I just made everything like 1.4-1.6 ethereum

@ROYBURSON Just like 1$ = 100 cents , 1 eth = 10^18 wei there is nothing more to the problem than this . I have editted my answer, read the comments I have posted in the editted code carefully .

give me a little to test and see if it works and ill accept, because previously when i was sending  const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei('1.4', 'ether'); i was getting way more then 1.4 eth in the metamask

it does not work. When i use the line  const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei(amountToSendStr, 'ether') i get 5902.95810359 Ethereum or $20,614,723.50 in the MetaMask which is not 1.4 eth right now. Its only around $5000. So this is not a solution. Maybe we need to specify the WEI into the metamask or something

@ROYBURSON https://pastebin.com/vpCE8k4Y . 1.4 eth should give 1400000000000000000 wei . Check the pastebin link

i ran the code with 1.4 as a string. It doesnt work. Sorry i cant click that link. Unsure about pastebin

when i send transaction i get printed to the console trying to send 1.4
myfunctions.js:5237 in WEI 1400000000000000000. So when i pass in 1.4 into the WEI function it gives me the correct amount of Wei. So i am sending the correct amount in WEI the problem is the extension i not recognizes it. If i send 1400000000000000000 it does not give me back 1.4 eth in the extension

@ROYBURSON   Now i see your problem . Metamask expects value field of transactionObject in hex . web3.utils.toHex(amountInWei) does the trick . I have editted  the answer again as EDIT2 .

@ROYBURSON Re-eddited to post the comnplete code snippet

let me check thank you and sorry for long delay

so i changed it to const amountInWei = web3.utils.toWei('1.4', 'ether'); and then set transaction object like this                                                             const transactionObject = {
from: userWallet,
to: recipientWallet,
value: web3.utils.toHex(amountInWei) // amountInWei
}; and it didnt work it still large number

if i send the value to 1335800000000000 then it send 1.38 eth which is close to what i want. I want to send 1.4. To get close i have to send                                                            const transactionObject = {
from: userWallet,
to: recipientWallet,
value:  1335800000000000
};

@ROYBURSON 1335800000000000 sends 1.38415 ether , because  1335800000000000 in hex is 1384153197974650880 in decimal . The code assumes you are supplying values in hex . If you want to send 1.3358 ether, you have to do this
 transactionObject = { from: userWallet, to: recipientWallet, value: web3.utils.toHex("1335800000000000") };
I have made an EDIT3 .

it is not working. I dont know how to upload photos to show you console log and proof lol I saved photo imgbb link you can see it here https://ibb.co/LShTFxX i printed hex and sent hex into the metamask. I will update code to my most recent

Your hex value is wrong for some reason . I took exactly your code initialised amountToSendFloat=1.6 . I also removed a console.log() statement because it was throwing an  error and removed networkStatus because its not relevant to the question . I got to send 1.6 ether
https://ibb.co/SBgg1tB
I checked your githubs myfunctions.js you are using amountInWei not amountInHex
`.  In your index.html you are using 1.5.0 version of web3, instead  use 1.5.2 .
Use - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.5.2/dist/web3.min.js

Also try and use chrome instead of firefox .

i did not update my githhub code yet i just ran that locally. I will update the github whenever i get it working. Is there any other hex functions? instead of that one and then maybe i can add a check and check if hex is correct before sending like const checkHex = checkHex(hexString, WeiString); and make it return true if it is corect hex and false otherwise. But i will try to check if adding the different script for web3 package works

i installed new script tag as you suggested but then i got 0.001145 eth when trying to send 1.2 eth.

i think there is an issue now actually with the library and how my code is implemented. So i accidentally did not uncomment the other version of the library. I made sure to comment out the other versions. So i defintly, have the 1.5.2 version running but then it doesn't recognize  window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum); So the metamask is not even calling now. If i use that package i need to edit this line

okay i got the code running with that library. Still not working. Hex definitely incorrect

thanks shadow i got it working now. It was some bugs in my code. I forgot to uncomment to conversion factor.  The hex is working now and i can send the correct value i will accept you answer. I will also update github and droplet
